# Thymeleaf th:inline=“javascript” (Whitelabel Error Page)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I don't know how to solve this problem

**Spring-side: role.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/role", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String role(Model model){
        List<Role> list=rImp.list();
        model.addAttribute("data",list);
        return "role";      
    }
```

**So if I now try inline="javascript":**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
       var List = /*[[${data}]]*/;
      /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

**when i run it i get this response:**

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> ```
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> Sun Jun 11 05:00:35 WET 2017
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> No message available
> ```

Comment: Look for an exception and a stacktrace in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `/*<![CDATA[*/var List = /*[[${data}]]*/;/*]]>*/` instead of `var List = [[${list}]];` as the list is getting added to model with this name.

Comment: Added CDATA tag in thymeleaf javascript tag.